react pagination how to return to page 0 when chagne the category
when i change the category the pagination stell in the same page number and the other category page turn to blank page i want when change the category the page go to 0.
this is the spring boot api for display all the posts by category
    @GetMapping("/public/posts/category")
    public ResponseEntity<PageResponse<PostResponse>> getAllPostsByCategory(
            @RequestParam(name = "category", required = false) String categoryName,
            @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0", required = false) int page,
            @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "10", required = false) int size
    ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getAllPostsByCategory(page, size, categoryName), HttpStatus.OK);
    }


and this is the react route for the category page
<Route path="/category/:category" element={<CategoryPage />} />

How can I track the parameter change? and when it chagne set the page to 0
  const { category } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    getPostsByCategory(category, pages, size).then((data) => {
      setContent(data.content);
      setTotalPages(data.totalPages);
    });
  }, [category, pages, size]);

  console.log(totalPages);

  return (
    <div className="h-[80vh] flex flex-col space-y-4 items-center justify-between">
      <div>
        {content.map((post) => (
          <Post key={post.id} post={post} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <Pageination pages={pages} setPages={setPages} totalPages={totalPages} />
    </div>
  );


You can add another useEffect with the dependency array of [category] and set the page value to 0 in there. This basically sets the page to 0 every time the category changes.
useEffect(() => {
  //pseudocode to represent changing the page value
  setPage(0)
}, [category])

